# How do I pass a prop for inline styling for React component with an array of data?

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

Here is my ShowData component that renders in my App.js and then in my index.js

```
import React from "react";
import SwatchData from "./SwatchData";
import { DataTestContainer } from "./DataTestContainer";

function ShowData(props) {
  const DataComponent = SwatchData.map(data => (
    <DataTestContainer color={data.color} key={data.id} hex={data.hex} />
  ));

  return (
    <div style={{ background: "{props.data.color}" }}>{DataComponent}</div>
  );
}

export default ShowData;
```

what I am looking to dynamically change the style of the final div based on the data.color prop

```
const SwatchData = [
  {
    id: 1,
    color: "red",
    hex: "#E73550"
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    color: "green",
    hex: "#A6A7DC"
  }
];

export default SwatchData;
```

Comment: Is there a question in there somewhere? What have you tried, is there an issue? [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @Drew - yup this is not working.....I want to change the background color of the div dynamically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of mapping though `SwatchData` and then trying to wrap it separately, do it all together -

```
function ShowData(props) {
  const DataComponent = SwatchData.map(data => (
    <div style={{ backgroundColor: data.color }}> 
      <DataTestContainer color={data.color} key={data.id} hex={data.hex} />
    </div>
  ));

  return DataComponent;
}
```

Also, you need to use `backgroundColor` to change the background color using inline styles.

Comment: I am getting an error of "Cannot read property 'color' of undefined"

Comment: I misunderstood the original question.  Looks like you aren't really using props at all.  I have updated my answer.

Comment: this is working however since ShowData is defined but never used I am getting an error

Comment: Where are you importing it in your app?

Comment: got it, I just needed to `export default ShowData;`

Answer (score 0):

Just extracting a single hex color value based on a named color

```js
const swatchData = [{
    id: 1,
    color: "red",
    hex: "#E73550"
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    color: "green",
    hex: "#A6A7DC"
  }
];

const props = {
  data: {
    color: 'red',
  },
};

const getColor = color => {
  const swatch = swatchData.find(swatch => swatch.color === color);
  return swatch ? swatch.hex : '#000';
}

console.log(getColor('red'));
console.log(getColor('green'));
console.log(getColor('royalPurple'));
console.log(getColor(props.data.color));
```

[edit]

Map the swatch data to JSX directly. Use the `id` as the key on the outer div so you don't get any react-key warnings, and pass the `color` and `hex` on to `DataTestContainer`.

```
function ShowData(props) {
  return SwatchData.map(({ color, hex, id }) => (
    <div key={id} style={{ background: color }}>
      <DataTestContainer color={color} hex={hex} />
    </div>
  ));
}
```

Comment: Do I update my SwatchData.js file to this minus the console.log? I am still having an issue in the ShowData component. When updating {{ backgrounColor : props.data.color }} I get an error of "Cannot read property 'color' of undefined"...I am new to react to go easy :)

Comment: @JoshCusick I see, I entirely misread your question earlier. Left it in case it's useful to anyone else later, and added how to directly map your swatch data to JSX.